# 3D viewer for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, 3d, viewer, cad

I am building a CAD marketplace in Rails and would like to know if there are any tools or library that allows me to 3D view CAD files stored on amazon s3.

Something that would be just like sketchfab's viewer : https://sketchfab.com/models/92f7a46ffeb9474f940ff2d4c7fdd73f
(they have a viewer API but only for models posted on THEIR website)

Thanks

Comment: with a simple search on google like cad file viewer with js or on browser, you can get some results that you can check

Comment: The problem with those is that I couldnt find any documentation for loading a CAD file from server and displaying it